# How to set up usage of a serial port?

Tags: linux, serial-port

I am working on Linux (TinyCore). As a part of work process, i must use a serial device to transmit data. However, i am having severe troubles with it.

The crux of the issue is that no data seem to be transmitted. On usage of command:

```
echo 'hello' > /dev/ttyS0
```

terminal seems to hang for a bit, then program finishes without any data seemingly transmitted (nothing on recieved side). When i try to recieve with:

```
cat < /dev/ttyS0
```

and try to send something from connected device, nothing seems to be recieved.

About settings of the device. here are outputs of corresponding commands i have run:

```
dmesg | grep tty
00:05: ttyS0 at I/0 0x3f8 (irq = 4, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
```

numbers acorrespond to what i can see from BIOS

```
stty -F /dev/ttyS0
speed 9600 baud; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>;
swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^0;
min = 1; time = 0;
-brkint -imaxbel
```

When testing with setserial i get:

```
setserial -g /dev/ttyS0
/dev/ttyS0, UART: 16550A, Port: 0x03f8, IRQ: 4
```

What can i do to determine the causes of why nothing is transmitted and fix it?

Comment: what does `/sbin/setserial -g /dev/ttyS0` say?.    Also, you might try using `minicom` and shorting the TX and RX pins together on your serial cable and see if you can see what you type

Comment: Added `setserial` call results; tyring shorting pins now

Comment: I'm sorry  `/sbin/setserial -v -g /dev/ttyS0` would have been better.  I forgot about the verbose flag.

Comment: it makes no difference on the output, it seems

Comment: It's been a while since I had to mess with it.  I was looking for how the modem control lines and flow control was set. Was looking to see how to sell if the `stty` had the options `clocal` `-ixon`, `-ixoff`, `-crtscts ` and `-crtsxoff `, which hopefully would disable the modem control lines and the flow control as one often needs for a 3 wire type serial connection.  Those are things that could be blocking you.  They are also things that you can control inside`minicom` to help figure out what settings you need.

Comment: Perhaps I am trying to remember how to do `stty raw` (in pieces).  Try that.  also try 'stty -a -F /dev/ttyS0` and it is supposed to show more settings.   It has been a while since I had to fight a serial port configuration

Comment: What scares me most: it may not a configuration issue; if that is the case, i will be lost on what to do

Comment: Is the port something funky, like a TTL level or inverted from standard TTL level serial port instead of RS232?  Many single board computers have non-RS232 serial ports these days.  Its the sort of thing you could look at an oscilloscope to check, if that is available to you.